# I can't stop my site from allowing me to scroll way past the footer

Tags: css, html

I cannot figure out why I can scroll past the footer of the site.
Any help would be really appreciated. 
I based this site off of a free template.

Thank you!

[My Website here](http://swaglifegaming.net/test/)

Comment: your problem exists only in Chrome browser! have you checked with Mozilla?

Comment: I just figured out that is does and I have no idea why... I need to to be compatible with all browzers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your website with just below change:

Use this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll">
```

Instead of :

```
<body data-spy="scroll" style ="overflow: visible;">
```

Comment: @Jeothesmar, Have u tried this? it worked?